# Can't boot install 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, wireless

It gets stuck every time I try instslling it, exactly the same as described here:

[Hangs after boot up cloud-init](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321968/ubuntu-server-20-04-2-lts-hangs-after-bootup-cloud-init-1781-yyyy-mm-dd-h)

To complicate matters further, it's not online, so what's on the bootable flash drive is all I've got.
This is because in the setup it's not giving me the option to connect to wifi and it's not accessible with an ethernet.

---

EDIT:

Embarrassing confession: I had mistakenly installed the server instead of the desktop. I don't know how I got that far without noticing.

As for the internet problems: my computer has a clash with Ubuntu that means I have to fix the wifi connection after each clean install. Only Ubuntu though, this didn't happen on Linux.
Using some suggestions on the forum fixes the wifi, but I still don't know what causes it.

Comment: Which Ubuntu 18.04 media?  Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, Ubuntu 18.04 Server, 18.04.1, 18.04.2 ... 18.04.5 - ie. we don't know what *media* you have and thus what's available to you (though as you're posting this online, you can walk extra files on media to your box). Does it boot to runlevel 1? or recovery options?  (ie. did you explore your install looking for issues?)

Comment: your title says cant boot install, while the question says you get stuck when trying to install ubuntu, which is it? booting ubuntu from a usb should bring you to a live desktop version to check it out before install

Comment: Thank you for the responses, but I have to make an embarrassing confession here.  I mistakenly installed the server instead of the desktop.